# How to setup distributed databases in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, failover

I'm looking at a way of achieving fail over and additionally load balancing over three databases in my Rails application.

The code that follows currently works with no issues, however if `db_1` is down then my application dies.

I would like to use `db_1` as the primary and the other two `db_2` and `db_3` as a fail over.

Additionally I would like to load balance them but that is a less important requirement.

**config/database.yml**

```
db_1:
  adapter: mysql2
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
  username: <username>
  password: <password>
  database: database_test
  host: 101.101.101.1

db_2:
  adapter: mysql2
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
  username: <username>
  password: <password>
  database: database_test
  host: 101.101.101.2

db_3:
  adapter: mysql2
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
  username: <username>
  password: <password>
  database: database_test
  host: 101.101.101.3
```

**app/models/ext_databases.rb**

```
class ExtDatabases < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.abstract_class = true
        establish_connection :db_1
end
```

**app/models/users.rb**

```
class Users < ExtDatabases
        Users.table_name = "ext_users"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be handled in MySQL side. You have a few options with MySQL like active-passive (replication), master-slave, cluster or sharding. Use those keywords on google to find the official MySQL documentation. Each strategies have their own advantages and disadvantages, and you need to understand them before a decision.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL already has a tool to do automatic failover, and it's aptly named [mysqlfailover](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqlfailover.html)

> This utility permits users to perform replication health monitoring
>   and automatic failover on a replication topology consisting of a
>   master and its slaves. The utility is designed to run interactively or
>   continuously refreshing the health information at periodic intervals.
>   Its primary mission is to monitor the master for failure and when a
>   failure occurs, execute failover to the best slave available. The
>   utility accepts a list of slaves to be considered the candidate slave.

Of course that means you do need to setup mysql replication but judging by the tone of your question you seem to have done so already.

mysqlfailover isn't the only option. Percona, a database that's fully compatible with mysql but independently developed has their own thing:

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.5/manual/failover.html